# Using try/catch to alert user of negative number entered, nestled in loop

Tags: java, loops, try-catch

I have created a program to find the average of positive numbers only. The program works fine, however, I am looking to improve it. At the moment when a user enters a negative number the loop ignores it. However I would like an error message to come up once the user enters a negative number.

I have done some research and I believe I need to add a try catch within my loop however, I'm not sure how I would implement it into my existing code.

Here is my code so far;

```
System.out.println("program to find the arithmetic mean (average) of a list of positive numbers  ");
System.out.println("=======================");
System.out.println();
System.out.print("How many numbers do you want to enter ? ");
numbers = inputLine.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter " +numbers+ " Numbers : "); 

for (start=0; start<numbers; start++) {
   int number;
   do {
      number = inputLine.nextInt();
   } while (number < 0);
   sum = sum + number;
}

if (numbers == 0) {
    System.out.print("program terminated......");
    System.exit(0);
}

armean = sum/numbers;
System.out.print("Average of all positive numbers entered is: " +armean);
```

Comment: Why do you need a `try-catch` specifically? You could simply check if the input is negative and display the error using `println()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `try-catch` since you don't get any exceptions here. User entering negative numbers is completely legitimate case. Just add some error message inside you `do-while` loop. E.g.

```
do {
    number = inputLine.nextInt();
    if (number < 0)
         System.out.println("Does not compute! Enter a positive number!");
} while (number < 0);
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I think I was confusing myself but this solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `try-catch`? You can simply check if the input number is negative and display an error message using `println()`.

Comment: Yes you're right, I guess I was simply over complicating my thought process. Thanks for the advice.